# How to separate SQL code in blocks in SSMS?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

In Oracle, I can separate blocks of PL/SQL code with the `/` character, and Oracle SQL Developer knows that when I run code with `Ctrl+Enter`, it's supposed to run all the code it finds until finding a `/`. Is there anything similar for SQL Server Management Studio (or T-SQL)?

Comment: You can highlight the SQL you want to run and then you you press execute (or [F5]), it'll only run the SQL highlighted.

Comment: You can also put a RETURN in

Answer (score 1):

As I note in the comment, one method is to highlight the SQL you want to execute, and then press the Execute Button (or <kbd>F5</kbd>) and only the SQL you have selected will be run.

[image]

This works in other Microsoft based IDEs too, such as Azure Data Studio:

[image]

Note, however, that when using such techniques that only variables defined in the highlighted SQL will be accessible. Take, the following statement for example:

```sql
DECLARE @MyString nvarchar(50) = N'This is my string';

SELECT @MyString;

SELECT CONCAT(@MyString, N' again');
```

If you highlight the last row only, you will get an error stating that the variable `@MyString` has not be declared:

[image]